# kotlin flows: make changes to a list of object and emit them

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-flow

I might be doing something wrong here, but I encountered a situation for which I don't see a correct solution. Let's say we have this class

```
class FilterGroup{
val id:Int
val possibleValues: List<String>
var selected: List<String>
}
```

in the context of an android app, a `ViewModel` downloads a list of `FilterGroup` and emits it to a `MutableStateFlow`, for the sake of semplicity:

```
private val _filters = MutableStateFlow({filterGroup1, filterGroup2, filterGroup3})
```

now a fragment can collect it and than change the value of the selected property based on user's actions:

```
filterGroup.selected = listOf(filterGroup.possibleValues.first())
```

now even if we notify the `ViewModel` that something as changed and try to emit `_filters` again, observers will not be notified about it because we directly changed a property of an object of a list, so `StateFlow` will prevent propagation because the changes are already there.

I though about using `SharedFlow` instead but that prevents me to read the value which I need for other purposes.
A solution to this would be to make an hard copy of the object every time they change, but this is a bit cumbersome as they're not this simple.

Is there a better solution to this problem, or is it better to rethink the whole thing by not having `var`s in the objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutable classes and StateFlows (or really Flows of any kind, but especially StateFlows) do not work well together. I recommend using immutable data classes and copying them when modifying, despite how cumbersome it is.

It's not so bad if you break out a separate function for it:

```
data class FilterGroup(
    val id: Int,
    val possibleValues: List<String>,
    val selected: List<String> = emptyList()
)

fun List<FilterGroup>.withSelectedValuesAtIndex(index: Int, vararg values: String): List<FilterGroup> = 
    toMutableList().also {
        it[index] = it[index].copy(selected = values.toList())
    }
```

Comment: I didn't know about the copy() method! I supposed this is indeed the fastest way